# RSS feed GET spam causes server CPU to run at 100%

Tags: cpu, spam-prevention, rss

I just transferred my site over to a new host and am seeing a tremendous amount of RSS feed spam.

Inside of my Apache logs I am seeing a bunch of GET requests to an RSS feed URL that doesn't exist (at least 20 per second):

```
2017-11-03T12:06:43.128572347Z [03/Nov/2017:12:06:42 +0000] 192.168.37.231 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" 2475
2017-11-03T12:06:43.389441028Z 192.168.37.231 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" 301 -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.389574732Z [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] 192.168.37.231 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.408464613Z 192.168.37.231 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" 301 -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.40850661Z [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] 192.168.37.231 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.411540849Z 192.168.37.231 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" 301 -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.411641255Z [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] 192.168.37.231 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" -
2017-11-03T12:06:43.468777814Z 192.168.37.231 - - [03/Nov/2017:12:06:43 +0000] "GET /?feed=ads HTTP/1.1" 503 2475
```

I'm not seeing anything else in my Apache logs that would be the cause of this CPU constantly running at 100% issue.

Inside of my php-fpm logs I am seeing:

```
2017-11-03T13:20:07.466546451Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:07] NOTICE: [pool www] child 117 started
2017-11-03T13:20:14.359871929Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:14] NOTICE: [pool www] child 91 exited with code 0 after 606.968836 seconds from start
2017-11-03T13:20:14.359917735Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:14] NOTICE: [pool www] child 127 started
2017-11-03T13:20:43.867682884Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:43] NOTICE: [pool www] child 90 exited with code 0 after 637.440716 seconds from start
2017-11-03T13:20:43.867694486Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:43] NOTICE: [pool www] child 135 started
2017-11-03T13:20:58.577836366Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 86 exited with code 0 after 662.714762 seconds from start
2017-11-03T13:20:58.578920398Z [03-Nov-2017 13:20:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 136 started
2017-11-03T13:22:25.865573438Z [03-Nov-2017 13:22:25] NOTICE: [pool www] child 89 exited with code 0 after 742.035998 seconds from start
```

And then eventually the fpm pool hits its limit:

```
2017-11-03T11:59:03.178672211Z [03-Nov-2017 11:59:03] WARNING: [pool www] server reached max_children setting (15), consider raising it
```

I have no idea how to prevent this from occurring, but it is causing my CPU to spin at 100% and makes my site inaccessible.

Further, I'm not sure why on my last host this wasn't an issue, but now that I've transferred this has become an issue.

How do I prevent these GET requests? I've been trying to block this in my .htaccess file, I've removed any RSS feed template files I had, and I've disabled RSS on the site - but none of that seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the solution from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/342774/use-apache-to-block-a-url-with-specific-query-string)?

In short:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} feed=ads
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```